# I keep getting an error when I try to define an element of a struct

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I am teaching myself C. I followed a tutorial and got an image to move around on the screen. Now I am trying to do it on my own and understand how to modularize my code and know whats going on with it.

I built a struct to get player coordinates and called it into my game_loop.h file. but it don't let me set variables from the struct. I tried to include just the important bits to keep it concise. Let me know if I need to post the whole code. 
What am I doing wrong.

```
//includes
#include "game_loop.h"

//main body
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
   //TODO make game menu and link it here

   //TODO make game loop and put it here
  initSDL();
  renderGame();
  handleEvent();

  //make game cleanup and put it her
  destroySDL();

  return 0;
}
```

int header file game_loop.h -->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "player.h"

#define pSIZE 64
#define wWIDTH 1280
#define wHEIGHT 720

//variables for starting SDL
SDL_Event event;
SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *render = NULL;

SDL_Surface *bgSurface = NULL;
SDL_Texture *bgTexture = NULL;

SDL_Surface *pSurface = NULL;
SDL_Texture *pTexture = NULL;

int flags = 0;       //window flags may need to change in the future 

struct Player player;
player.x = 600;
player.y = 300;

void initSDL()
{
//initializing SDL
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)!= 0)
{
    printf("ERROR starting SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
}else{printf("Starting SDL: Successful.\n");}
```

in a player.h file -->

```
struct Player{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?, how can we know what you are doing wrong if we can't read the code?

Comment: In global scope you are assigning. Put it inside a method. `player.x=600`

Comment: I added the code to the question. Sorry its my first time asking a question in any forum on coding. And I am having a hard time with the formatting of the code for the question. I will try to put the whole code in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lines of executable code outside of a function:

```
Player player;
player.x = 600; 
player.y = 300;
```

The first line defines a variable.  That is OK.  The next two lines are not, as they are statements.

You need to initialize the struct at the time it is defined.  You can do it as follows:

```
Player player = { 600, 300 };
```

Also, it's not a good idea to define variables in header files.  If a header is used in multiple source files, you'll end up with errors due to multiple definitions.

In your header file, variables should be declared as `extern` without an initializer:

```
extern Player player;
```

Then you would put the definition with the initializer in *exactly* one source file.

Similarly for functions, put a declaration of the function in the header, and the definition of the function in one source file.

Comment: EDIT: this seemed to have worked tho i like the multi-line format better.  if i define it in a function can i use multiple line statements? it has worked when following tutorials so I think i am a little confused by the difference.
                                                                                                                
 thank you i will try that and google more on it. I just wanted a point in the right directions.

Comment: @Nelyn If you move the assignment statements to inside of a function, yes you can do that.  You just need to make sure you do it early before any other function attempt to read it.  The initialization syntax is preferable however.  Note also that you can break up the initializer on multiple lines for readability if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just temporary I am planing on defining stuff in main to be passed to the headers but I am just trying to get the stuff working first. Awesome on the breaking up lines. I thought of that and was gunna do that once the struct grows. I just have two variables in it to test. This is my first time making header files so thank you so much for the info and patience.